# Character is algebraic number

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory, characters

I'm reading the book "Representation Theory of finite groups" the chapter about characters. Suppose that $V$ is a KG module where $G$ is a group and $K$ is a field. Let $\chi$ be the group character. There is Theorem which states that if $K$ is a number field then $\chi(g)$ is an algebraic number for all $g \in G$.

If $T$ be the matrix representation we can easily deduce that $\{T(g)\}^n=I$ for some positive integer $n$. So all the eigenvalues are $n$th root of unity. So $\chi(g)$ is a sum of roots of unity which is algebraic.

I don't know why we need $K$ be a number field.

Comment: I suppose $K$ has to have characteristic zero. Also, the character values are algebraic integers.

Comment: I think something is missing here. The value will in fact be in $K$ for trivial reasons.

Comment: Could it be that the author meant algebraic _integer_?

Comment: Actually, in the Theorem it has additional statement that if dim$(V)=t$ then $|\chi(g)|\leq t$. I think we need that $K$ be a number field for this statement.

Comment: If I see this correctly, you do not need a number field for this additional statement, if you have $\dim(V) = t$, then $\chi(g)$ is the sum of $t$ roots of unity and thus $|\chi(g)| \leq t$ by triangle inequality.